# Kid or young adult live action TV show. Giant Robots?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, young-adult

Boy finds some device that puts him in a giant robot suit and can see other similar Robots. Humans cannot see them. Was possibly 90s I could be wrong. We could see like a weird coloured outline of them and they come for him at his home later in story. All I remember my mum called me to do something been searching for years. I'm in UK. Maybe started at school and bunked off.

Comment: How giant were the robots? 10-12 feet tall? Taller than buildings? Reaching up into the clouds?

Comment: I think like bigger than buildings